# Laravel Sorting (orderBy or sortBy) is no working to sort database results

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6.x and have been trying to sort orders ascendingly by the time they were created. This is what I tried. I tried changing the positions of `orderBy` and `sortBy`, but it didn't change anything.

```
 public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::select("*", DB::raw("count(*) as order_count"))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("coupon"))->sortBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();

        return view('admin.order.index', compact('orders'));
    }
```

So can you please tell me why this code is not sorting properly? Thank you for your support!

Comment: if you are selecting everything then you need to also group by everything selected (except the count) otherwise you'll get nonesense in each row (assuming it works at all)

Answer (score 1):

sortBy is used by collection, for a query, you have to use a orderBy :

```
public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->get();

        return view('admin.order.index', compact('orders'));
    }
```

you can also use `latest()`

```
public function index()
    {
        $orders = Order::latest()
            ->get();

        return view('admin.order.index', compact('orders'));
    }
```

You can't use a count a groupBy here, or you would get a single line.

Provide more information about what you are trying to do (Do you want to have the number of order per coupon ?

Edited :

To get your order groupby coupon :

```
$coupons = Coupon::with(['order' => function($query){
    $query->latest();
})->withCount('order')->get();
```

then you can use it :

```
@foreach($coupons as $coupon)
    Number of Order : {{ $coupon->order_count }}
    <br>
    Orders :
    @foreach($coupon->orders as $order)
         {{ $order->[...] }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: All I want to achieve is, to get all orders grouped by coupon and these grouped orders should be sorted by descending order.